# Breaking cumulative transformations

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I am using `DrawingContext` object to draw series of rectangles. My requirement is like this:

1. First Rectangle I want to place at(100, 100)
2. Second Rectangle I want to place at(200, 200)
3. Third Rectangle I want to place at(0, 0)

I am using transformation matrix to achieve it as follows:

1. To position the first rectangle at (100, 100) I use the following:

   drawingContext.PushTransform(new TranslateTransform(100, 100));
   drawingContext.DrawRectangle(Brushes.Blue, null, new Rect(0, 0, 100, 100));
2. To position the second rectangle at (200, 200) I use the following: 
   drawingContext.PushTransform(new TranslateTransform(100, 100));
   drawingContext.DrawRectangle(Brushes.Blue, null, new Rect(0, 0, 100, 100));
3. To position the third rectangle at (0, 0) I can use (-200, -200).
   But I am curious is there any way I can replace this cumulative chain and overwrite the entire matrix with new position
   Like: drawingContext.PushTransform(new TranslateTransform(0, 0));

This is possible on WinForms graphics by setting Transform property as follows:

```
g.Transform = new Matrix();
```

Is there any way in which we can break this cumulative chain in WPF

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One possible way to solve is to call Pop() multiple times. But as Pop() not just pops transformations, but also pops the last opacity mask, opacity, clip etc it doesn't suit my needs.

Other possible solution I just worked out is to maintain additional Matrix **state** object separately.

Whenever we push any transformation onto `DrawingContext` object we also need to prepend that object onto this **state** object.

Finally when we want to totally break this chain we can inverse the state of the **state** matrix and push that onto `DrawingContext` object. This will set the transform state to identity matrix on DrawingContext object.

```
    //Keep a state matrix
    Matrix state = new Matrix();

    //First transform
    MatrixTransform transform1 = new MatrixTransform();
    Matrix matrix1 = new Matrix();
    matrix1.OffsetX = 100;
    matrix1.OffsetY = 100;           
    transform1.Matrix = matrix1;

    drawingContext.PushTransform(transform1);
    state.Prepend(matrix1);
    drawingContext.DrawRectangle(..);

    //Second transform
    MatrixTransform transform2 = new MatrixTransform();
    Matrix matrix2 = new Matrix();
    matrix2.OffsetX = 400;
    matrix2.OffsetY = 400;           
    transform2.Matrix = matrix2;

    drawingContext.PushTransform(transform2);
    state.Prepend(matrix2);
    drawingContext.DrawRectangle(..);


    //Finally reset to identity matrix.

    //Inverse the state matrix
    state.Invert(); 
    //Apply this inverted matrix to DrawingContext to get identity matrix.
    MatrixTransform transform3 = new MatrixTransform();
    transform3.Matrix = state;
    drawingContext.PushTransform(transform3);
    drawingContext.DrawRectangle(...);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
drawingContext.PushTransform(new TranslateTransform(100, 100));      
drawingContext.DrawRectangle(Brushes.Blue, null, new Rect(0, 0, 100, 100));
drawingContext.Pop();
```

The [Pop()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingcontext.pop%28v=vs.100%29.ASPX) method resets the transform to the state it was before the call to `PushTransform()`.

Comment: Pop() is one possible option. but I need to know with single assignment is it possible to break the entire chain. In this particular example, I need to call Pop() twice.